# Other versions of a weak Ito formula?

Tags: stochastic-processes, sobolev-spaces, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, weak-derivatives

I am aware that this question is rather unspecific, but I was curious what versions of the Ito formula for Sobolev functions exist (and what methods are used to prove them).The only result I am aware of is the following, but I would be interested in versions with (maybe) even more relaxed assumptions.

Let $f\in W_{\text{loc}}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with $p>1+\frac{n}{2}$, then we have
$$f(W_{t})=f(0)+\int_{0}^{t}\nabla f(W_{s})\cdot dW_{s}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\varDelta f(W_{s})\:dW_{s},$$
where $W_{\cdot}$ is an $n$-dimensional Brownian motion.

Proof:We define $\rho(t,x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi t)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\exp\left(-\frac{\vert x\vert^{2}}{2t}\right)$. Let us first consider the case $n>2$. Let $f_{n}$ be a regularizing sequence for $f$, which we obtained by a convolution with the usual mollifier. Then $f_{n}\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $f_{n}$ converges to $f$, uniformly on compact sets, so that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(W_{t})=f(W_{t}),$$
 for any $t\geq0$. By the standard Ito formula, we have
$$f_{n}(W_{t})=f_{n}(W_{0})+\int_{0}^{t}\nabla f_{n}(W_{s})\cdot dW_{s}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\varDelta f_{n}(W_{s})\:ds.$$
 Further, by the Ito isometry,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_{0}^{t}(\nabla f_{n}(W_{s})-\nabla f(W_{s}))\cdot dW_{s}\right)^{2}\right]$$
 $$=\int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{E}\left[\vert\nabla f_{n}(W_{s})-\nabla f(W_{s})\vert^{2}\right]\:ds$$
 $$=\int_{0}^{t}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\vert\nabla f_{n}(x)-\nabla f(x)\vert^{2}\rho(s,x)\:dx\:ds=:I_{n}.$$

If $p>n$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}I_{n}=0$ by Lebesgue's theorem, since $\nabla f\in C\cap L^{\infty}$, and so the integrand converges to zero pointwise and is dominated by the integrable function $\|\nabla f_{n}-\nabla f\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{2}\rho$ .
On the other hand, if $1+\frac{n}{2}<p\leq n$, we have $\vert\nabla f\vert^{2}\in L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for some $q>1+\frac{n}{2}$. Let $q'$ be the conjugate exponent of $q$, then we have
$$q'=1+\frac{1}{p-1}<1+\frac{2}{n}$$
 and therefore, as $\rho\in L^{p}$ for any $p\in(0,1+\frac{2}{n})$, $\rho\in L^{q'}((0,T)\times\mathbb{R}^{n})$. By Hölder's inequality, we obtain

$$I_{n}\leq\left\Vert \vert\nabla f_{n}-\nabla f\vert^{2}\right\Vert _{L^{q}((0,T)\times\mathbb{R}^{n})}\|\rho\|_{L^{q'}((0,T)\times\mathbb{R}^{n})}\rightarrow_{n\rightarrow\infty}0.$$
 Finally,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left\vert \int_{0}^{t}(\varDelta f_{n}(W_{s})-\varDelta f(W_{s}))\:ds\right\vert \right]$$
 $$\leq\int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{E}\left[\left\vert \varDelta f_{n}(W_{s})-\varDelta f(W_{s}))\right\vert \right]\:ds$$
 $$=\int_{0}^{t}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\vert\varDelta f_{n}(x)-\varDelta f(x)\vert\rho(s,x)\:dx\:ds.$$
 By applying Hölder's inequality with the conjugate exponent of $p$, which we call $p'$, the last term is

$$\leq\|\varDelta f_{n}-\varDelta f\|_{L^{p}((0,T)\times\mathbb{R}^{n})}\|\rho\|_{L^{p'}((0,T)\times\mathbb{R}^{n})}\rightarrow_{n\rightarrow\infty}0,$$
 since $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ in $W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and the assumption $p>1+\frac{2}{n}$ implies $p'<1+\frac{2}{n}$. We have, as as $\rho\in L^{p}$ for any $p\in(0,1+\frac{2}{n})$,
$\|\rho\|_{L^{p'}((0,T)\times\mathbb{R}^{n})}<\infty.$

In conclusion, we showed that the proposed form of Ito's formula holds a.s. for every t>0.
 In the case $n\leq2$, the hypothesis $p>1+\frac{n}{2}$ implies that $p>n$
  and the claim can be proved as before.

Comment: You have a typo on the first equation? $dW_s$ of the last term shall be $ds$.

Comment: Is there a book or paper where I can find this result? Is it true for any Ito process?

Comment: This questions seems very relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76609/generalized-itos-formula