# Can we apply Ito formula to quadratic variation of $C^1$ function of semimartingale?

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm looking at conversion between Ito and Stratonovich for certain classes of functions, and was wondering whether we can apply Ito's to a $C^1$ function in a covariation expression: Ito's applies normally only to $C^2$ function $F(X)$ giving
$$
dX_t = F'(X_t)dX_t + \dfrac{1}{2} F''(X_t) d \langle X \rangle_t 
$$
which for quadratic co-variation with some other semimartingale $W$ becomes (where the finite variation term disappears) (integrating from $0$ to $t$)
\begin{align}
\langle X,W \rangle &= \langle \int dX_t + W \rangle \\
&= \langle \int F'(X_s)\,  dX_s,W\rangle \\
&= \int F'(X_s) \, d\langle X,W\rangle
\end{align}
and I'm wondering whether since we only have the expression of $F'$ if this can be done more generally with $C^1$ functions, or if perhaps the "hypothetical" 2nd order term in any approximation (for example a Stone-Weierstrass polynomial one approximating $F$) is too large in the limit.

Answer (score 1):

**Convex case**

A very general formula is the [The Itô-Tanaka-Meyer Formula](https://almostsuremath.com/2020/10/12/the-ito-tanaka-meyer-formula/)
 (here too ["Itô–Tanaka formula and local times of semimartingales"](https://www.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/user_upload/gubinelli/stochastic-analysis-ss20/sa-ss20-script-15.pdf))

Theorem 2 (Itô-Tanaka-Meyer) Let X be a semimartingale, $f\colon{\mathbb R}\rightarrow{\mathbb R}$ be convex, and $L^x_t$ be a jointly measurable version of the local times. Then,

$\begin{aligned} f(X_t)=& f(X_0)+\int_0^t f^\prime(X_-)dX+\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty L^x_t\,f^{\prime\prime}(dx)\\ &\quad+\sum_{s\le t}\left(\Delta f(X_s)-f^\prime(X_{s-})\Delta X_s\right) \end{aligned}$

almost surely, for each $t\ge0$.

See here ["Itô's Formula for Non-Smooth Functions"](https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/3684) for the case of generalized first/second derivatives. Here too [Other versions of a weak Ito formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521208/other-versions-of-a-weak-ito-formula)

**$C^1$ and Martingale**

As mentioned here [Applying Ito's formula on a $C^1$ only differentiable function yielding a martingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2636969/applying-itos-formula-on-a-c1-only-differentiable-function-yielding-a-martin)

Assume that we know that $f(s+t,x+B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale for any fixed $s \geq 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and assume that $f$ grows at most sub-exponentially, we can apply the martingale property and Itô's formula to deduce that

$$f(t,B_t) = f(0,B_0) + \int_0^t f'(s,B_s) \, dB_s.$$

**$C^1$ extensions**

In the works

- ["Ito formula for cl-functions of semimartingales"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01303801.pdf)
- ["A $C^{
  0,1}$-functional Itˆo’s formula and its applications in mathematical finance"](https://hal.science/hal-03105342/document)
- ["Extended Itô calculus for symmetric Markov processes"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41714085?seq=2),

they obtain some generalized formulas for some specific settings.

**Fukushima decomposition**

As mentioned in ["Ito formula for cl-functions of semimartingales"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01303801.pdf), we have that if $f \in C^1(R)$ and $X$ is semimartingale, then $f(X)$ is a Dirichlet process (i.e. the sum of a martingale and a process with zero-energy) and is not in general a semimartingale (they reference an article in French, but I would like to write the counterexample down once I understand it.).